# How to output a vector of boolean values with rows in the data frame that have similar values?

Tags: r

So I have a data frame with 2 columns that have TRUE and FALSE values.

I want to find the rows that contain TRUE for both columns in a given row, and create a vector with Boolean values, only outputting TRUE if it meets the criteria above.

E.g.

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE), b = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE))
```

So with the code, it should output a vector with TRUE,FALSE,FALSE, since the first row contains two TRUE values, so it output TRUE while the rest output FALSE.

Comment: `dat$a & dat$b`

Comment: `Reduce(\`&\`, dat)` if you want to automate the above logic if you have more than 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
apply(dat,1,all)
```

Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

So you can anytime achieve this with your logic only...

In this case you have to look for "And" operator which has the property to return True only if both the values are True.

```
dat$a & dat$b   #will retrun the desired output.
```